# convert yearly observations to daily observations

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have a data frame that looks

```
a <- c(118200,251482,325641)
b <- c(251463,524198,623144)
c <- c(251796,201534,62498)
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(a,b,c), row.names = c('2013','2014','2015')) 
> df
          a      b      c
  2013 118200 251463 251796
  2014 251482 524198 201534
  2015 325641 623144  62498
```

Instead of the year, I want to get daily information by dividing each observation by 365 and the last day of each year sums up to yearly total. i.e.

```
                   a      b      c
  2013-01-01    326.83 688.94  689.85
  2013-01-02    647.67 1377.88 1379.70
  2013-01-03    971.50 2066.82 2069.56
       .           .      .      .
       .           .      .      .
  2013-12-31    118200  251463 251796
```

and same for the year 2014 and 2015. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could do:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df, keep.rownames = TRUE)
cols <- setdiff(names(df), "rn")

df <- df[, .(Day = seq(as.Date(paste0(rn, "-01-01")),
                       as.Date(paste0(rn, "-12-31")),
                       by = "day")),
         by = names(df)][
           , (cols) := lapply(.SD, function(x) round( (x / .N) * (1:.N), 2)),
           .SDcols = cols, 
           by = rn][, "rn" := NULL]
```

Output for beginning of `2013` and end of `2015`:

```
              a         b        c        Day
   1:    323.84    688.94   689.85 2013-01-01
   2:    647.67   1377.88  1379.70 2013-01-02
   3:    971.51   2066.82  2069.56 2013-01-03
   4:   1295.34   2755.76  2759.41 2013-01-04
   5:   1619.18   3444.70  3449.26 2013-01-05
  ---                                        
1091: 322072.33 616315.02 61813.09 2015-12-27
1092: 322964.50 618022.27 61984.32 2015-12-28
1093: 323856.67 619729.51 62155.55 2015-12-29
1094: 324748.83 621436.76 62326.77 2015-12-30
1095: 325641.00 623144.00 62498.00 2015-12-31
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, for a, the value of  2013-01-02 should be  323.84*2 = 647.68, and for 2013-01-03 it should be 323.84*3 = 971.49...and so on. It's the same for b and c. Can you help me to achieve that?

Comment: You're welcome! Even easier, in that case we just multiply by the corresponding row number - see my edit.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to generalize the column names? I mean instead of saying a=a, b=b, c=c can we generalize someway? My actual data has 290 columns :).